# Laravel Atomic Lock doesnt lock correctly

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, laravel-8

because my database is slow and I get a lot of API requests on the same time. I want to prevent the method from being executed twice at exactly the same time. I'm trying to implement the Laravel Atomic Lock as a solution (as described in: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#atomic-locks ) by the following way:

```
$lock = Cache::lock("service-{$id}", 10);

try
{
    $lock->block(5);
    // Lock acquired after waiting a maximum of 5 seconds...
} catch (LockTimeoutException $e)
{
    // Unable to acquire lock...
    return null;
}
//Execute code when lock is achieved
optional($lock)->release();
//Release lock when complete.
```

But for some reason I am still getting duplicate executions of the code despite the lock. I am using Redis as Cache driver. Anything I am doing wrong?